# How do you make javascript code execute *in order*

Tags: javascript, ajax, order-of-execution

Okay, so I appreciate that Javascript is not C# or PHP, but I keep coming back to an issue in Javascript - not with JS itself but my use of it.

I have a function:

```
function updateStatuses(){

showLoader() //show the 'loader.gif' in the UI

updateStatus('cron1'); //performs an ajax request to get the status of something
updateStatus('cron2');
updateStatus('cron3');
updateStatus('cronEmail');
updateStatus('cronHourly');
updateStatus('cronDaily');

hideLoader(); //hide the 'loader.gif' in the UI

}
```

Thing is, owing to Javascript's burning desire to jump ahead in the code, the loader never appears because the 'hideLoader' function runs straight after.

How can I fix this? Or in other words, how can I make a javascript function execute in the order I write it on the page...

Comment: The Promise is the best object for handle all async requests. [fix async requests with Promise object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47719849/7487135)

Answer (score 16):

The problem occurs because AJAX is in its nature asynchronus. This means that the `updateStatus()` calls are indeed executed in order but returns immediatly and the JS interpreter reaches `hideLoader()` before any data is retreived from the AJAX requests.

You should perform the `hideLoader()` on an event where the AJAX calls are finished.

Comment: Exactly, JS doesn't wait for the updateStatus jobs to finish before starts the next jobs. If cron1 has to finish before cron2 starts, etc. You will need to set each updateStatus to run on Success of the previous call.

Answer (score 14):

You need to think of JavaScript as event based rather than procedural if you're doing AJAX programming.  You have to wait until the first call completes before executing the second.  The way to do that is to bind the second call to a callback that fires when the first is finished.  Without knowing more about the inner workings of your AJAX library (hopefully you're using a library) I can't tell you how to do this, but it will probably look something like this:

```
showLoader();

  updateStatus('cron1', function() {
    updateStatus('cron2', function() {
      updateStatus('cron3', function() {
        updateStatus('cronEmail', function() {
          updateStatus('cronHourly', function() {
            updateStatus('cronDaily', funciton() { hideLoader(); })
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
});
```

The idea is, `updateStatus` takes its normal argument, plus a callback function to execute when it's finished.  It's a reasonably common pattern to pass a function to run `onComplete` into a function which provides such a hook.

**Update**

If you're using jQuery, you can read up on `$.ajax()` here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Your code probably looks something like this:

```
function updateStatus(arg) {
  // processing

  $.ajax({
     data : /* something */,
     url  : /* something */
  });

  // processing
}
```

You can modify your functions to take a callback as their second parameter with something like this:

```
function updateStatus(arg, onComplete) {
  $.ajax({
    data : /* something */,
    url  : /* something */,
    complete : onComplete // called when AJAX transaction finishes
  });
```

}

Answer (score 10):

I thinks all you need to do is have this in your code:

```
async: false,
```

So your Ajax call would look like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "something.html for example",
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            context: document.body,
            success: function(response){

                //do stuff here

            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Sorry, The requested property could not be found.");
            }  
        });
```

Obviously some of this need to change for `XML`, `JSON` etc but the `async: false,` is the main point here which tell the JS engine to wait until the success call have returned (or failed depending) and then carry on. 
Remember there is a downside to this, and thats that the entire page becomes unresponsive until the ajax returns!!! usually within milliseconds which is not a big deals but COULD take longer.

Hope this is the right answer and it helps you :)

Comment: This one did the trick. Simple and concise solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: While it worked this isn't an awesome answer. You want JS to be asynchronous. There's many advantages and scenarios where you want it to go do it's own thing and turning it all off for your whole app is just uncommon.

I'd recommend using a promise library instead. Here's a great tutorial. http://dailyjs.com/2014/02/20/promises-in-detail/

Answer (score 5):

We have something similar in one of our projects, and we solved it by using a counter. If you increase the counter for each call to `updateStatus` and decrease it in the AJAX request's response function (depends on the AJAX JavaScript library you're using.)

Once the counter reaches zero, all AJAX requests are completed and you can call `hideLoader()`.

Here's a sample:

```
var loadCounter = 0;

function updateStatuses(){
    updateStatus('cron1'); //performs an ajax request to get the status of something
    updateStatus('cron2');
    updateStatus('cron3');    
    updateStatus('cronEmail');
    updateStatus('cronHourly');
    updateStatus('cronDaily');
}

function updateStatus(what) {
    loadCounter++;

    //perform your AJAX call and set the response method to updateStatusCompleted()
}

function updateStatusCompleted() {
    loadCounter--;
    if (loadCounter <= 0)
        hideLoader(); //hide the 'loader.gif' in the UI
}
```

Comment: Hi Prutswonder, I just tried this and it works! I like the solution

Comment: Ed, if you like one of these solutions, could you mark your choice of the best solution by clicking the checkbox next to that person's answer?

Comment: +1 Probably better than my solution for such a deeply nested series of callbacks

Comment: You might want the `loadCounter < 0` case to cause an error, since if that ever happens, it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the execution order of the code.

The reason that the loader image never shows, is that the UI doesn't update while your function is running. If you do changes in the UI, they don't appear until you exit the function and return control to the browser.

You can use a timeout after setting the image, giving the browser a chance to update the UI before starting rest of the code:

```
function updateStatuses(){

  showLoader() //show the 'loader.gif' in the UI

  // start a timeout that will start the rest of the code after the UI updates
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    updateStatus('cron1'); //performs an ajax request to get the status of something
    updateStatus('cron2');
    updateStatus('cron3');
    updateStatus('cronEmail');
    updateStatus('cronHourly');
    updateStatus('cronDaily');

    hideLoader(); //hide the 'loader.gif' in the UI
  },0);
}
```

There is another factor that also can make your code appear to execute out of order. If your AJAX requests are asynchronous, the function won't wait for the responses. The function that takes care of the response will run when the browser receives the response. If you want to hide the loader image after the response has been received, you would have to do that when the last response handler function runs. As the responses doesn't have to arrive in the order that you sent the requests, you would need to count how many responses you got to know when the last one comes.

Comment: Thanks to Guffa and Dr. Sbaitso, I understand a lot more know what's going on under the hood, I'm going to give some of your suggestions a try and see what I can make work!

Answer (score 1):

Install Firebug, then add a line like this to each of showLoader, updateStatus and hideLoader:

```
Console.log("event logged");
```

You'll see listed in the console window the calls to your function, and they will be in order. The question, is what does your "updateStatus" method do?

Presumably it starts a background task, then returns, so you will reach the call to hideLoader before any of the background tasks finish. Your Ajax library probably has an "OnComplete" or "OnFinished" callback - call the following updateStatus from there.

Comment: the updateStatus method fires off a jquery ajax call. The reason I can't hide the loader in the 'Onsuccess' callback is because I need to wait for multiple calls to complete. But using the 'counter' approach given below I've got a workaround

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you don't want to do a synchronous operation. Embrace Async, that's what the A in AJAX stands for.

I would just like to mention an excellent analogy on sync v/s async. You can read the [entire post on the GWT forum](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/faca1575f306ba0f?pli=1), I am just including the relevant analogies.

> Imagine if you will ...
>
> You are sitting on the couch watching
>   TV, and knowing that you are out   of
>   beer, you ask your spouse to please
>   run down to the liquor store   and
>   fetch you some. As soon as you see
>   your spouse walk out the front   door,
>   you get up off the couch and trundle
>   into the kitchen and open   the
>   fridge. To your surprise, there is no
>   beer!
>
> Well of course there is no beer, your
>   spouse is still on the trip to   the
>   liquor store. You've gotta wait until
>   [s]he returns before you can   expect
>   to have a beer.

But, you say you want it synchronous? Imagine again ...

> ... spouse walks out the door ... now,
>   the entire world around you stops, you
>   don't get to breath,   answer the
>   door, or finish watching your show
>   while [s]he runs across   town to
>   fetch your beer. You just get to sit
>   there not moving a   muscle, and
>   turning blue until you lose
>   consciousness ... waking up   some
>   indefinite time later surrounded by
>   EMTs and a spouse saying oh,   hey, I
>   got your beer.

That's exactly what happens when you insist on doing a synchronous server call.

Answer (score 0):

move the updateStatus calls to another function. make a call setTimeout with the new function as a target.

if your ajax requests are asynchronous, you should have something to track which ones have completed. each callback method can set a "completed" flag somewhere for itself, and check to see if it's the last one to do so. if it is, then have it call hideLoader.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions for handling all async requests is the **'Promise'**.
The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation.

**Example:**

```
let myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // We call resolve(...) when what we were doing asynchronously was successful, and reject(...) when it failed.
  // In this example, we use setTimeout(...) to simulate async code. 
  // In reality, you will probably be using something like XHR or an HTML5 API.
  setTimeout(function(){
    resolve("Success!"); // Yay! Everything went well!
  }, 250);
});  

myFirstPromise.then((successMessage) => {
  // successMessage is whatever we passed in the resolve(...) function above.
  // It doesn't have to be a string, but if it is only a succeed message, it probably will be.
  console.log("Yay! " + successMessage);
});
```

[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Examples)

**If you have 3 async functions and expect to run in order, do as follows:**

```
let FirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    FirstPromise.resolve("First!");
});
let SecondPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

});
let ThirdPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

});
FirstPromise.then((successMessage) => {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "type",
    url: "url",
    success: function(response){
        console.log("First! ");
        SecondPromise.resolve("Second!");
    },
    error: function() {
        //handle your error
    }  
  });           
});
SecondPromise.then((successMessage) => {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "type",
    url: "url",
    success: function(response){
        console.log("Second! ");
        ThirdPromise.resolve("Third!");
    },
    error: function() {
       //handle your error
    }  
  });    
});
ThirdPromise.then((successMessage) => {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "type",
    url: "url",
    success: function(response){
        console.log("Third! ");
    },
    error: function() {
        //handle your error
    }  
  });  
});
```

With this approach, you can handle all async operation as you wish.