# my javascript code is not executed in the right order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make javascript code execute *in order*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637626/how-do-you-make-javascript-code-execute-in-order)

```
var cek = false;

function checkForm()
{
    var user = document.forms["LoginForm"]["user"].value;
    var pwd = document.forms["LoginForm"]["pwd"].value;
    AJAXfunc("checkidpass.php?id="+user+"&pass="+pwd,function()
    {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
        {
            $("#LoginRes").html(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == "")
                cek = true;
        }
    }); //---> 1

    return cek; //---> 2
}
```

I want to ask why "return cek;" (part 2) is executed before the AJAXfunc (part 1)? And I want to know how to make it executed in the right order.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The first "A" in "AJAX" stands for **Asynchronous**.

Comment: any idea how to make it executed in the right order? Thanks

Comment: @darkstallion if you're not sure how to think of it, think of it like `window.setTimeout` where you don't know the value of `ms`.

Comment: It already is executing in the right order. It's not possible to structure code like that in an asynchronous system.

Comment: I think I need to learn more about asynchronous system. I never code in an asynchronous system before. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @darkstallion, that sounds exactly like my answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand your issue, you need to understand **asynchronous** methods. A simple google will give you a plethora of reading material. I suggest starting here:

[Mastering Ajax, Part 2: Make asynchronous requests with JavaScript and Ajax](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ajaxintro2/)

**Hint:** What you're doing now will **never** work - unless you choose to make it a synchronous function (not recommended).

Comment: `Hint: What you're doing now will never work` Not even if you modify `AJAXfunction`s [`open`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29) 3rd parameter to `false`? :o

Comment: @PaulS., I thought it best to avoid the synchronous vs async discussion and point the OP to resources that would teach the root cause of the problem. Based on your comment however, I've updated my hint. My original statement was correct though, what they are doing right now will never work.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the AJAX call is asynchronous.

The `AJAXfunc` call is executed before the `return` statement, but the anonymous function that you provide in the `AJAXfunc` call is called later.

The way to make the callback run before the `return` statement is to make the AJAX call synchronous. However, that is genrally not a good idea, as that will make the browser freeze while it is waiting for the response.

The usual way to handle this is to use a callback in the `checkForm` function:

```
function checkForm(callback) {
  var user = document.forms["LoginForm"]["user"].value;
  var pwd = document.forms["LoginForm"]["pwd"].value;
  AJAXfunc("checkidpass.php?id="+user+"&pass="+pwd,function() {
    if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200)) {
      $("#LoginRes").html(xmlhttp.responseText);
      callback(xmlhttp.responseText == "");
    }
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
checkForm(function(cek) {
  if (cek) {
    // ok
  } else {
    // not ok
  }
});
```

Comment: what happens if `xmlhttp.readyState != 4`? your callback will never be called!

Comment: @drinchev: Yes, that state isn't handled in the original code either. The result would be (if it had worked) that the variable would be undefined.

Comment: Yes it will be undefined, but your `checkForm(function(cek) { if ( cek ) { // ok } else { // this will never be called } });` right?

Comment: @drinchev: Yes, it will. If the server returns something other than an empty result, it will be called. It's only if the server call fails that the callback won't be called, as the AJAX code doesn't handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is async so async functions like you `AJAXfunc` doesn't block your program until it completes. That's why events and callbacks are heavily used in javascript.

e.g. your code with callbacks would look something like :

```
function checkForm(callback)
{
    var user = document.forms["LoginForm"]["user"].value;
    var pwd = document.forms["LoginForm"]["pwd"].value;
    AJAXfunc("checkidpass.php?id="+user+"&pass="+pwd,function()
    {
        if ((xmlhttp.readyState == 4) && (xmlhttp.status == 200))
        {
            $("#LoginRes").html(xmlhttp.responseText);
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == "")
                return callback(true);
        }
        return callback(false);
    }); 
}

checkForm( function (result) { 
    var cek = result;
    // Rest of your code for manipulating DOM or something else where you need cek.
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You best re-structure your code to trigger a callback when you get the response.

ie.
1. make checkForm have a callback argument
2. activate that callback with the result
3. have the rest of the code in the callback instead of following the return of the function

for example:

```
// before (wrong):
result = checkForm();
handleResult1(result);
handleResult2(result);

// after (correct):
checkForm(function(result) {
    handleResult1(result);
    handleResult2(result);
}
```