# subscribe function doesn't work correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

in this piece  of code the subscribe function executes after the last line in loadFromDB function:

```js
  loadFromDB(){
    const loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'pleas wait'
    });
    loading.present();
    this.getInterviewFromDB()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.events = data;
        console.log( 'before');
      });
    this.getMeetingsFromDB().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.events.concat(data);
    });
    loading.dismiss();

    console.log( 'after');
  }
```

the loading is present and dismiss before loading any data from database
and this is the output of the log

[image]
 illustrates that line under the subscribe function Execute after the console.log inside it ...can any body explain to me .. ?!

Comment: It is a common problem that developers encounter with JavaScript. So you are in familiar territory. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382567  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637626

Answer (score 1):

This makes perfectly sense. You are subscribing to asynchronous steams. You cant expect them to finish in order. If you want them to finish at the same time you can do something like this:

```
Observable.forkJoin(this.getInterviewFromDB(), this.getMeetingsFromDB())
    .subscribe(res => {
       let interviews = res[0];
       let meetings = res[1];
    })
```

Comment: mr.Robin thanks for your  caring  but it still unclear  to me .. can u explain it to me a bit later ?!

Comment: It is `RxJs`. You can read more about it there: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS Remember everthing is async.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way callbacks work.  `subscribe` takes a callback function as an argument.  I suggest you learn what callbacks are and how they work before continuing.

Here is a little bit of information on how `subscribe` works: [ReactiveX subscribe function](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html)

Robin provides a good solution in his answer with `forkJoin`.  `forkJoin` joins the values emitted by multiple Observables into an array and creates a new Observable.  You can then subscribe to this Observable, just like Robin did in his example, to get the array value which is the first argument of the callback.