# Angular 4: cannot subscribe observable value from CanActivate AccessGuard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i followed a lot of tutorials and tried many combinations but cannot make this work.

I need to let a route be available when a user is logged. If he's not i need to redirect him to the homepage `(this._popupService.setCallbackRoute(route.url.join('/')))` and show a popup `(this._popupService.showPopUp())` which lets him login or register.

I cannot get the syncronized value from the authService. This is my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
        {path: '', component: HomepageComponent},
        {
            path: 'protectedRoute',
            component: SubmitComponent,
            data: {requiresLogin: true},
            canActivate: [AccessGuard]
        }
    ),
    ...
]
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
 @Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    private loggedIn: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    get isLoggedIn() {
        return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
    }

    login(user: IUser) {
        return this._http.get('assets/api/responseSuccess.json?email=' + user.email + '&password=' + user.password)
            .map((responseLogin => {
                const jsonResponse = responseLogin.json();
                if (jsonResponse.response === 'success') {
                    const userResponse: IUser = jsonResponse.user;
                    this._sessionService.setUserSession(userResponse);
                    this.loggedIn.next(true);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    this._customFlashMessages.show('Got error login, please check your credentials and try again!');
                    return false;
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

**accessGuard.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {PopUpService} from './popup.service';

@Injectable()
export class AccessGuard implements CanActivate {
    loggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private _popupService: PopUpService, private router: Router) {
        this.loggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        const requiresLogin = route.data.requiresLogin || false;
        if (requiresLogin) {
            this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe( // even tried with .map()
                result => {
                    console.log(result); // Logs a promise object
                    if (!result) {
                        console.log("protected route"); // Never reached
                        // If not logged in shop popup and stay on that page
                        this._popupService.showPopUp();
                        this._popupService.setCallbackRoute(route.url.join('/'));
                        return false;
                    }
                    console.log('logged in'); // Never reached
                    return true;
                });
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I tried several things. My code works if i directly check the sessionStorage('user') but not working with observable.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: From your explanation, popup has to be not in guard, but in homepage component, inside which one can implement  `ngOnInit()` a check if user `isSignedIn` and if not, fire the popup with the login form. Guard has to only redirect to the homepage before returning `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct answer, the problem was in the logic inside the subscribe method.

Here's the correct **accesGuard.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AccessGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private _popupService: PopUpService, private router: Router) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        const requiresLogin = route.data.requiresLogin || false;
        if (requiresLogin) {
            this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe(
                result => {
                    if (!result) {
                        // If not logged in shop popup and stay on that page
                        this._popupService.showPopUp();
                        this._popupService.setCallbackRoute(route.url.join('/'));
                        this.router.navigate(['/']);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                });

            return true;
        }else{

        return true;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Robin Dijkhof logic is allowed in canActivate method. In this way you can use the same procedure for every authenticated routes.

Comment: Logic is allowed, but displaying a model isn't just logic. Also are you sure this is working. Subscribe is asynchronous so this looks weird. I suspect it will never be false. If it works you are lucky, but what happens if there is a small delay.

Comment: Uhm.. it works even in production server. Do you mean that i should return the this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe() result instead of returning true at the end?

Comment: take a look at this question to see what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847183/subscribe-function-doesnt-work-correctly

Comment: Yes i understood. I updated my code with the else statement. This should work in every case.

Comment: That is not exactly what I meant. Try this for example: `this.authService.isLoggedIn.delay(1000)`. And add the followinf import: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an observable.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const requiresLogin = route.data.requiresLogin || false;
    if (requiresLogin) {
        return this.authService.isLoggedIn;
    }
    return Observable.of(false);
}
```

Comment: And how can i show the popup and put the login inside every private page?

Comment: I don't think that is possible from a guard. I think it would be better to redirect to a dedicated loginpage and send the requested with it. After a succesfull login you can redirect back.

Comment: I would like to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935721/how-to-return-observable-from-subscribe

Comment: See my comment above. Thank you for your answer.