# Openlayers 3 vector source issue

Tags: openlayers-3

Inside the ajax callback I have all the features as expected, but I don't have them outside.

What am I missing ?

```js
var geojsonSource = new ol.source.Vector();
$.ajax('assets/data/data.geojson').then(function(response) {
    var geojsonFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var features = geojsonFormat.readFeatures(response, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326'});

    geojsonSource.addFeatures(features);
    console.log(geojsonSource.getFeatures()); // this work
});
console.log(geojsonSource.getFeatures()); // this doesn't work
```

Comment: This is not OpenLayers (or vector source) problem, this is caused because JavaScript is asynchronous and the last line is executed *before* the AJAX handler function is executed (it is only called when the remote data is fully loaded).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make javascript code execute \*in order\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637626/how-do-you-make-javascript-code-execute-in-order)

Answer (score 1):

Everything's fine with your snippet. As @kryger said, AJAX is Asynchronous Javascript and XML. So, register a listener to know when your features are added to the source, like:

```
geojsonSource.on('addfeature', function(event){
    console.log(geojsonSource.getFeatures());

});
```