# Instruction gets executed before the one above in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I execute the code below:

```
const https = require('https');

const req = https.get('https://www.google.com', (res) => {
   console.log('message');
})

console.log('message2');
```

The output I get is:

```
message2
message
```

Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make javascript code execute \*in order\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637626/how-do-you-make-javascript-code-execute-in-order)

Comment: you need to watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) to get more understanding of asynchronous behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `https.get` is asynchronous, so NodeJs don't wait this call and immediately executes `console.log('message2');`.
That way we can not to wait async call completion and continue doing something. After that request finished successfully you'll get `console.log('message');`